# Trying to Install Ubuntu on DELL Inspirion 15 3000-RST Issues

Tags: system-installation, rst

1. Erased Windows 11
2. I'm trying to install latest Ubuntu
3. Using Flash Drive with Ubuntu
4. receiving mssg:"This computer usues Intel RST (Rapid Storage Technology). You need to turn off RST before installing Ubuntu."
5. Scanned the "bar-code" which took me to the Official Ubuntu Documentation site.
6. Tried the suggestion "How to safely re-configure Windows to use AHCI". Still no luck.

Any direction is highly appreciated.
Thanks,
Benny

Comment: My Dell 5310 with Intel 11th Gen chip worked with RST on with 22.04. It has a NVMe drive and Kubuntu used driver I had not seen before.  Kernel modules: vmd, ahci The vmd is default driver, but I have connected other external drives. I did have to turn off Windows fast start up/hibernation and Windows bitlocker. I normally suggest changing to AHCI, and forgot. Bit surprised it then worked with Intel RST on.